# Passé simple et passé composé

Tags: passé-composé, passé-simple

> Il le disait si gaiement que je ne pus m'empêcher de rire.
>   (Romains)
>
> Soudain il sut qu'elle l'avait trompé.

Using the perfect (passé composé) to replace the past historic  (passé simple) may we rewrite previous sentences as

> Il le disait si gaiement que je n'ai pas pu m'empêcher de rire.
>
> Soudain il a su qu'elle l'avait trompé.

?

In general this replacement is always valid? That is, the perfect may always replace the past historic (in conversation and ordinary writing)?

Comment: Always valid ? Oui! Absolument. D'ailleurs on ne fait plus apprendre le passé simple à l'école. Après... mais **ce n'est possiblement que moi et mes potes**, quand, comme dans ton exemple, il est question de soudaineté, brutalité, instantanéité... au passé, tout temps autre que le passé simple me pique les oreilles autant que les yeux.

Comment: Sans compter qu'avec certains verbes conjugués avec l'auxiliaire être et dont l'adjectif tiré du participe passé est usuel, (e.g. *il est mort*) on peut ne pas vraiment savoir s'il s'agit d'un passé composé ou d'un présent + adjectif attribut.

Comment: @aCOSwt > ces 2 commentaires ressemblent furieusement à une réponse...

Comment: @Laurent S. Peut-être. Mais comme je les crois ne valoir que pour moi et mes potes... je préfère la relative discrétion des commentaires. ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt Merci pour les commentaires. Tu ne vas pas poster une réponse ?

Comment: @dimitris : Et si... muni de tous les éléments fournis d'abord par jlliagre et ensuite par mon second commentaire... tu la rédigeais toi-même *LA* réponse... je crois que cela te serait beaucoup plus profitable... ! (Sans compter que si j'ai compris comment fonctionne le site... cela te vaudrait... KUDOS!) ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt Merci. Je vais essayer:-)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le passé simple est utiliser pour narrer. Remplacer par du passé composé n'a pas la même signification en réalité cf. première réponse de aCoswt. Sauf que j'ajouterai que si c'est toujours valide, ça n'a pas le même sens.